# Java scanner count numbers that are in an interval

Tags: java

I'm new with java and i have to write a code that asks the user two numbers an interval. Then the user must introduce n numbers and the program must return how many numbers belong to that interval.

I've tried to do this and this is what i have:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumsInter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc;
    int a,b,nums,count;
    sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Write two numbers a and b(a<=b)(interval): ");
    a=sc.nextInt();
    b=sc.nextInt();
    count=0;
    System.out.println("write a number: ");
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        nums=sc.nextInt();
        if (a<=nums && nums>=b){
            count= count + 1;
        } else {
            count= count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count +" numbers are included in ("+a+","+b+")");

    }
}
```

Example: If the user writes 2 and 6, and then 4,4,3,1 the output should be 3.

As I am a newbie i don't know how can i do this the good way, can someoen help?
PD: How can i break the loop so i can get the output?
Thank You!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: First of all, this is merely about reviewing your code; codereview.stackexchange.com would fit better. Second, from glancing at it; code looks fine. Formatting could be improved; and naming: give your variables names that say what they are. "a" says ... nothing. Call it "lowerBoundaryOfInterval" ... and voila everybody sees directly what its intention is. "count" means nothing; whereas "countOfNumbersWithinInterval" ... I guess you get it.

Comment: the problem is that i cant get this work well, i don't know how to get a loop with scans

Comment: what you exactly want to print

Comment: "*the problem is that i cant get this work well*" that is not proper problem description. You need to be more specific about how you want your code to behave and how it behaves instead. Also you can add example of input and expected result (with explanation why such result is expected and other not).

Comment: Never put additional information in comments; update your question. There are plenty of solutions for stopping the loop; like: checking for special values (for example null). Or by expecting a STRING as input (meaning that you have to try to convert to a number); so that user can type "quit" when done

Comment: @Jägermeister If the user writes a char i think the loop stops, but it's not counting well how many numbers are in the interval

Comment: You think or you tried? Because, without trying it would assume that your program dies with an exception when you enter a non-number and press enter.

Comment: @Jägermeister It returns 0 numbers are included...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
  ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Enter the numbers you want to test, enter 'stop' to stop");
    boolean userInput = true;

    while(input.hasNextInt() && userInput){
        if(input.hasNext("stop")){userInput = false;}
        numbers.add(input.nextInt());
        }
```

Where you have a loop that checks if there is a next int while at the same time checking to see if the user is done or not.

And them something like this to print your answer

```
for(int i =0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    testNum = numbers.get(i);
        if(testNum > lowerLimit && testNum < upperLimit){
        count++;
        }
}
System.out.println(count + " valid numbers have been entered!");
```

Answer (score 0):

take an `int [] no_between_max&min` after take the input from user and store in this array. after that take a for loop and compare the value of array with max and min ant increase the `count` variable.

```
int noOfItem=sc.nextInt();
    int [] no_between_max_min = new int[noOfItem];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfItem;i++){
        no_between_max_min[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<no_between_max_min.length;i++){
        if(no_between_max_min[i]>=a&&no_between_max_min[i]<=b){
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Panoremux apply in your code and let me know is it working for you

Comment: I've applied your code and it is working better than mine, but the result is still bad, ty anyways :D

Comment: I can just enter 3 numbers and if i enter 3 3 3 4 it returns a bad result

Comment: u take one more for inside the for loop and compare the like no_between_max_min[j]==no_between_max_min[j+1])
and if it will equal then simple decrease the count variable like count--